# How could I shorten this trivial data tree algorithm in C++?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

It creates a data tree and a "random"/pseudo-random number.
Then it looks for the path to the "randomly" generated number and if the whole thing was found.
Surely there is a better way but I just can't think of one.
Also, I see a bug, but it's not even worth to fix it, because there must be a better way anyway (I mean if for whatever reason integer "in" is above or below 10 or 0).

I just can't find anything about it. Is it simply not possible?

````cpp
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;

    Node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

Node* build()   {
    struct Node* root = new Node(5);

    root->right = new Node(3);
    root->left = new Node(7);

    root->right->right = new Node(1);
    root->right->left = new Node(4);
    root->right->right->right = new Node(0);
    root->right->right->left = new Node(2);

    root->left->right = new Node(6);
    root->left->left = new Node(9);
    root->left->left->right = new Node(8);
    root->left->left->left = new Node(10);

    return root;
}

void worker(int in, Node* root) {
    bool found = false;
    string path = "";
    int val = 0;

    if (in > root->data)    {
            if (in > root->left->data)  {
                if (in > root->left->left->data)    {
                    found = true;
                    path = "root->left->left->left";
                    val = root->left->left->left->data;
                }
                else if (in < root->left->left->data)   {
                    found = true;
                    path = "root->left->left->right";
                    val = root->left->left->right->data;
                }
                else {
                    found = true;
                    path = "root->left->left";
                    val = root->left->left->data;
    }
            }
            else if (in < root->left->data) {
                found = true;
                path = "root->left->right";
                val = root->left->right->data;
            }
            else {
                found = true;
                path = "root->left";
                val = root->left->data;
    }
    }

    else if (in < root->data)   {
        if (in > root->right->data) {
            found = true;
            path = "root->right->left";
            val = root->right->left->data;
        }
        else if (in < root->right->data)    {
                if (in > root->right->right->data)  {
                    found = true;
                    path = "root->right->right->left";
                    val = root->right->right->left->data;
                }
                else if (in < root->right->right->data) {
                    found = true;
                    path = "root->right->right->right";
                    val = root->right->right->right->data;
                }
                else {
                    found = true;
                    path = "root->right->right";
                    val = root->right->right->data;
    }
        }
        else {
            found = true;
            path = "root->right";
            val = root->right->data;
        }
    }
    else {
    found = true;
    path = "root";
    val = root->data;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: You are checking nodes one at a time but what if there were 1000 nodes?  You need to use recursion to build and search a tree - the function should look at the current node and then call itself for each child.

Comment: Also – the C++ language provides a broad selection of "container classes," of course including trees, specifically so that *you* don't have to write them and debug them yourself.  While it might be "a worthy *academic exercise"* to write such an algorithm from scratch, just to understand how they work, that's all that it would be.  With C++, you can easily stand on the shoulders of giants.  Grab a class and simply use it, knowing that it will work.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was sure that a better solution must exist. How could I solve this using recursion? Thanks!


It's simply for exercise yes^^

Comment: You don't need to use recursion, you could just use a while loop like the other answer suggested.  Maybe I should add an example to my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you have to write your own binary tree instead of using `std::set` then you don't want to hardcode all the paths through the tree - there could be thousands of nodes and you saw what a pain it was to deal with just 11.

There are two ways to approach this problem: you can use iteration (a while loop) to move through the binary tree or you can use recursion.  Some problems are simpler with iteration and some are easier with recursion.  So I have done it both ways so you can compare.

With a while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(int data) : data(data), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

struct AddResult
{
    Node *node;
    bool inserted;
    std::string path;
    
    AddResult(Node *node, bool inserted, std::string path) : node(node), inserted(inserted), path(path) {}
};

AddResult add(Node* node, int value)
{
    bool inserted = false;
    std::string path = "root";

    while (node != NULL && value != node->data)
    {
        if (value > node->data)
        {
            // add to the right
            if (node->right == NULL)
            {
                node->right = new Node(value);
                inserted = true;
            }
            path = path + "->right";
            node = node->right;
        }
        else
        {
            // add to the left
            if (node->left == NULL)
            {
                node->left = new Node(value);
                inserted = true;
            }
            path = path + "->left";
            node = node->left;
        }
    }
    return AddResult(node, inserted, path);
}

struct FindResult
{
    Node *node;
    bool found;
    std::string path;
    
    FindResult(Node *node, bool found, std::string path) : node(node), found(found), path(path) {}
};

FindResult find(Node* node, int value)
{
    bool found = true;
    std::string path = "root";

    while (node != NULL && value != node->data)
    {
        if (value > node->data)
        {
            // add to the right
            if (node->right == NULL)
                found = false;

            path = path + "->right";
            node = node->right;
        }
        else
        {
            // add to the left
            if (node->left == NULL)
                found = false;
                
            path = path + "->left";
            node = node->left;
        }
    }
    return FindResult(node, found, path);
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = new Node(5);
    printf("%d was made the root of the tree\n", 5);

    // add all the odd values from 1 to 10 inclusive
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i+=2)
    {
        AddResult result = add(root,i);
        if (result.inserted == false)
            printf("%d was already in the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
        else
            printf("%d was added to the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
    }
    // add all the even values from 1 to 10 inclusive
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i+=2)
    {
        AddResult result = add(root,i);
        if (result.inserted == false)
            printf("%d was already in the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
        else
            printf("%d was added to the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
    }

    puts("");

    // find all the values from -1 to 12 inclusive
    for(int i=-1; i<=12; i++)
    {
        FindResult result = find(root,i);
        if (result.found == false)
            printf("%d was not found in the tree\n", i);
        else
            printf("%d was Found in the tree at %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/BJeL1A6Gu

With recursion: the add or find function should check the current node and if that node isn't the right one then it should call the function again with either the left side or the right side:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(int data) : data(data), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

struct AddResult
{
    Node *node;
    bool inserted;
    std::string path;
    
    AddResult(Node *node, bool inserted, std::string path) : node(node), inserted(inserted), path(path) {}
};

AddResult add(Node* node, int value, std::string path = "root")
{
    if (value == node->data)
        return AddResult(node, false, path); // already in tree

    if (value > node->data)
    {
        // add to the right
        if (node->right != NULL)
            return add(node->right, value, path + "->right");
        else
        {
            node->right = new Node(value);
            return AddResult(node->right, true, path + "->right");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // add to the left
        if (node->left != NULL)
            return add(node->left, value, path + "->left");
        else
        {
            node->left = new Node(value);
            return AddResult(node->left, true, path + "->left");
        }
    }
}

struct FindResult
{
    Node *node;
    bool found;
    std::string path;
    
    FindResult(Node *node, bool found, std::string path) : node(node), found(found), path(path) {}
};

FindResult find(Node* node, int value, std::string path = "root")
{
    if (value == node->data)
        return FindResult(node,true,path);
    
    if (value > node->data)
    {
        // add to the right
        if (node->right != NULL)
            return find(node->right, value, path + "->right");
        else
            return FindResult(NULL,false,path);
    }
    else
    {
        // add to the left
        if (node->left != NULL)
            return find(node->left, value, path + "->left");
        else
            return FindResult(NULL,false,path);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = new Node(5);
    printf("%d was made the root of the tree\n", 5);

    // add all the odd values from 1 to 10 inclusive
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i+=2)
    {
        AddResult result = add(root,i);
        if (result.inserted == false)
            printf("%d was already in the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
        else
            printf("%d was added to the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
    }
    // add all the even values from 1 to 10 inclusive
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i+=2)
    {
        AddResult result = add(root,i);
        if (result.inserted == false)
            printf("%d was already in the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
        else
            printf("%d was added to the tree at: %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
    }

    puts("");

    // find all the values from -1 to 12 inclusive
    for(int i=-1; i<=12; i++)
    {
        FindResult result = find(root,i);
        if (result.found == false)
            printf("%d was not found in the tree\n", i);
        else
            printf("%d was Found in the tree at %s\n", i, result.path.c_str());
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/BJi6F66zO

The main problem with this program is that you need to choose the root of the tree or write a whole bunch of code to balance the tree after adding to it.  Using `std::set` would do all of that for you. If you used `std::set` the whole program would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> tree;

    // let's add an item now so we can see what happens if we add it again later    
    auto result = tree.insert(5);
    printf("%d was added to the tree: %d\n", 5, *result.first);

    // add all the values from 0 to 10 inclusive
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        auto result = tree.insert(i);
        if (result.second == false)
            printf("%d was already in the tree: %d\n", i, *result.first);
        else
            printf("%d was added to the tree: %d\n", i, *result.first);
    }

    puts("");

    // find all the values from -1 to 12 inclusive
    for(int i=-1; i<=12; i++)
    {
        auto result = tree.find(i);
        if (result == tree.end())
            printf("%d was not found in the tree\n", i);
        else
            printf("%d was Found in the tree: %d\n", i, *result);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/Hk8FHpTMu

Comment: This is a detailed answer and answers all my questions! Thank you very much! I am overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly,your "worker" function used a lots of "if…else if…else" styling which could make your algorithm hardly extend.Maybe you can try this code

```
Node * prt = root;
string val,path="root"; 
while(prt){ 
 if(prt.data>in){
  path+="->right";
  prt=prt->right;} 
 else if(prt.date<in){
  path+="->left";
  prt=prt->left;} 
 else{
  break;} 
}
val=root+"->data";
```